# Building Vue app with target "Web Component" - SCSS styling not applied?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

So I have a very small app I've built that I want to integrate into a website as a web component. So I build the app using `vue-cli-service build --target wc --inline-vue --name name-of-component`

However the SCSS styling is not included? It works fine in the live reload during development. The SCSS file is imported in the main.js file like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';
import './assets/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but a workaround is to import the SCSS within the `<style>` block instead of `<script>`:

```html
<style lang="scss">
@import '~@/assets/main.scss';
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which is a mix of importing like tony19 said:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import '~@/assets/main.scss';
</style>
```

Then using `sass main.scss main.css` and including a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">` in the same document as the web component. That way the styling was applied correctly.

Also generally I would recommend hosting any assets such as css, fonts, images, svgs, etc. etc. on a CDN and using the full url to the asset in the web component so that you don't have to include these on the web pages using the component.